# How can I create a dynamic stylesheet using an ID selector?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I want to be able to get the following code to work:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var style = document.createElement( "style" );

style.type = "text/css";
style.media = "print";
style.styleSheet.cssText = "#menu {display:none;}";
head.appendChild( style );
window.print();
```

The problem is that it ends up with the following style:
UNKNOWN {display:none;}

I've also tried using addRule with the same result, well actually it errors with "Invalid argument" and nothing is set.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to dynamically hide some elements within a given page to not print, these elements use different tags, formats, and classes, so there is no generic way to exclude them (at least that I can think of) without using an ID selector.

This is for a business application on an intranet using IE7.

My only current workaround is to send this information to an ASP to just return it back as a stylesheet so I can use it as an href stylesheet since that is all I can think of to dynamically create a stylesheet using ID selectors.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var style = document.createElement( "style" );
style.type = "text/css";
style.media = "print";
style.text = "#menu {display:none;}";
head.appendChild( style );
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it works if you just use `.innerHTML`. I'm on Chrome though, it looks like you're on Internet Explorer. Nevertheless, using `.innerHTML`, you can simply set the contents (i.e. between `<style>` and `</style>`).

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var style = document.createElement( "style" );

style.type = "text/css";
style.media = "print";
style.innerHTML = "#menu {display:none;}";
head.appendChild( style );
window.print();
```